# check for if the button clicked is correct, then create a (response);

Tags: javascript, button

Apology for the trouble. I am trying to learning on creating a simple Quiz. I am trying to get javascript to "listen" to the **button's value clicked**, and if it is **align with the answer**, I want it to **create a console.log("correct)**".

I had been trying for multiple method to try to prompt an response including which is about creating a function to individually check if which button is clicked then prompt a response. However, i think this is not doable because once the first question is answered correctly, then i didn't know how to proceed to make the supposedly "correct button" for question 2 to prompt the response. The "correct button" keep get stuck with the "correct button for question 1. Therefore, i am trying different approach which I am trying to get if the button's value is align the answer then prompt a response.

```js
const myTextArea = document.getElementById("question")
const btnGlobal = document.querySelectorAll("button")
const btnOne = document.getElementById("button-one")
const btnTwo = document.getElementById("button-two")
const btnThree = document.getElementById("button-three")
const btnFour = document.getElementById("button-four")


let questions = [{
    question: "What did you eat today?",
    choiceA: "Fried Noodle",
    choiceB: "Chinese Dumpling",
    choiceC: "Chicken Rice",
    choiceD: "Pan Mee",
    answer: "B",
},
{
    question: "What did you drink today?",
    choiceA: "Carbonate Drinks",
    choiceB: "3 Layer Tea",
    choiceC: "Coffee",
    choiceD: "Milo",
    answer: "D",
},
{
    question: "What did you do today?",
    choiceA: "Jogging",
    choiceB: "Swimming",
    choiceC: "Watching Movie",
    choiceD: "Sleeping",
    answer: "C",
}]

let currentQuestion = 0;

function ansCheck() {
    var selectAns = questions[currentQuestion].answer
    if (target.value == selectAns) {
        console.log("correct");
    } else {
        console.log("wrong");
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="main-body">
        <p id="question">Input your question here.</p>
        <div class="btn-list">
            <button class="button" onclick="ansCheck()" id="button-one" value="A" type="submit">Choice A</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="ansCheck()" id="button-two" value="B" type="submit">Choice B</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="ansCheck()" id="button-three" value="C" type="submit">Choice C</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="ansCheck()" id="button-four" value="D" type="submit">Choice D</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+quiz+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: There should be a very clear error in your developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first: change the html buttons this way:

```
<button class="button" onclick="ansCheck('A')">Choice A</button>
<button class="button" onclick="ansCheck('B')">Choice B</button>
<button class="button" onclick="ansCheck('C')">Choice C</button>
<button class="button" onclick="ansCheck('D')">Choice D</button>
```

then change the function:

```
function ansCheck(userAnswer) {
    var selectAns = questions[currentQuestion].answer
    if (userAnswer == selectAns) {
        console.log("correct");
    } else {
        console.log("wrong");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` into your inline click handler

```
<button class="button" onclick="ansCheck(this);" id="button-one" value="A" type="submit">Choice A</button>
<button class="button" onclick="ansCheck(this);" id="button-two" value="B" type="submit">Choice B</button>
<button class="button" onclick="ansCheck(this);" id="button-three" value="C" type="submit">Choice C</button>
<button class="button" onclick="ansCheck(this);" id="button-four" value="D" type="submit">Choice D</button>
```

retrieve the currently clicked target from your click event handler

```
function ansCheck(target) {
    var selectAns = questions[currentQuestion].answer
    if (target.value == selectAns) {
        console.log("correct");
    } else {
        console.log("wrong");
    }
}
```